# Wildcard dns as subdomain in localhost using apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain, localhost, wildcard

i am developing a web application in Zend Framework running in apache server (xampp). The site can actually be accessed by http://localhost/sitename . It is present in c:/xampp/htdocs/sitename/

I wanted to create wildcard dns so a specific user can access my webpage like username.localhost.... i will fetch the username as parameter and show the customized settings for him..

Can someone help me with it... Do i have to first assign a servername for my localhost/sitename ? and then think about adding subdomain wildcards ? Please enlight me...

Answer (score 1):

DNS is used to get to the server, then the Apache bindings are using to determine which site handles the request.

So first I would add the DNS wildcards and make sure that pinging them will resolve to the IP address on the Apache server.  That's the first step.

Then add bindings in Apache to have it handled by the correct site and dropped off in the correct sub-folder.